# Offline software like phpmyadmin to open .sql locted in my PC

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have a .sql file in my computer and I use msql command line client to open it presently. But it lacks graphical interface. Is there any software that i can install in my windows 7 PC so that i will have an interface similar to phpmyadmin to open .sql file saved in my PC?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try MySQL Workbench. Here's the link

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Also, if you only need to read the contents of the .sql file, you can use Notepad++ or any other text file editor. But I would suggest Notepad++ since it supports alot of files and also provides formatting too.

http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 0):

Export it as csv and use excel